# Getting error while doing face recognition implementation using java and opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-recognition

I am developing a face recognition app using java and opencv library. I have used the facerecognition code available on [this link](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/FaceRecognition.java?r=02385ce192fb82f1668386e55ff71ed8d6f88ae3).

But I am getting some error like this....

```
Could not find method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.width, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.convertFloatImageToUcharImage

Could not find method com.googlecode.javacpp.FloatPointer.put, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.findNearestNeighbor

Could not find method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvMat.get, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.findNearestNeighbor

Could not find method com.googlecode.javacpp.FloatPointer.capacity, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.floatPointerToString

Could not find method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvOpenFileStorage, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.loadTrainingData

Could not find method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvOpenFileStorage, referenced from method com.kgec.mediaondemand.FaceRecognition.storeTrainingData
```

*Can anyone help me?*

Comment: Can someone kindly answer this question??

Comment: People would be more likely to help if you show them your efforts in resolving the issue *yourself*.